# How to get back media if media not restored during restoring without affecting recent chats and media?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore, media-files, chat

So I backed up my whatsapp a month ago and then while restoring I was not able to find a wifi source so it just stopped restoring media, only the chats were restored. Now after a month use I have more chats and some media, what do I do to bring back all the older media and keep all the latest chats and media?